# ICS Event Updates for Google Calendar and Outlook for Windows

Tags: calendar, outlook, google-calendar-api, icalendar

**Problem:**

If I create an ICS file with a particular uid and sequence = 0, sending that ICS to Google Calendar or Outlook for Windows creates the event successfully.
If I create another ICS with the same uid and sequence 1

- Sending that event to Google Calendar updates it successfully
- Sending it to Outlook for Windows causes a duplicate event to be created, and deleting either event on the calendar deletes them both

**Potential Workaround:**

Would the following workaround work for both Google Calendar and Outlook for Windows?

- When an event is rescheduled, attach both a cancellation ICS and a
  new ICS with a different uid and sequence 0.
- The goal is that the original event would be deleted and recreated with new event time in both Google Calendar and Outlook for Windows

**Sample ICS Files (Current Files, not workaround)**

original Event:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:GMT -4
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16011104T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYHOUR=2;BYMINUTE=0;BYMONTH=11
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010311T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=2SU;BYHOUR=2;BYMINUTE=0;BYMONTH=3
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN=test@gmail.com;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:test@gmail.com
ORGANIZER;CN="Test Scheduling":mailto:test@s-3er8nc12r9xwme7e7orvha5os.k5hihmay.k.apex.sandbox.salesforce.com
DTSTART:20140728T090000Z
DTEND:20140728T100000Z
DTSTAMP:20140718T085713Z
LOCATION:DM Scheduling will contact you at the time of your call to connect the call.
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:0
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800a08K0000008HIxXIAW20140718T085712Z00000000000000
DESCRIPTION:This is test #5 (7/18/14)
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:[P3006954]:3Call-Marina test/Marina Invividual Exp
PRIORITY:5
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Reschedule:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:GMT -4
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16011104T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYHOUR=2;BYMINUTE=0;BYMONTH=11
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010311T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=2SU;BYHOUR=2;BYMINUTE=0;BYMONTH=3
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN=test@gmail.com;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:test@gmail.com
ORGANIZER;CN="Test Scheduling":mailto:test@s-3er8nc12r9xwme7e7orvha5os.k5hihmay.k.apex.sandbox.salesforce.com
DTSTART:20140729T100000Z
DTEND:20140729T110000Z
DTSTAMP:20140718T090944Z
LOCATION:DM Scheduling will contact you at the time of your call to connect the call.
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:1
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800a08K0000008HIxXIAW20140718T085712Z00000000000000
DESCRIPTION:This is test #5 (7/18/14)
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:[P3006954]:3Call-Marina test/Marina Invividual Exp
PRIORITY:5
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Did you manage to reschedule the event in some Microsoft calendar? I have the same problem with Windows calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Rescheduling is possible with Outlook. There must be some little thing that you're missing. Try sending a simplest possible reschedule, with just UID, sequence and new times? Your UID is quite long, and the spec doesn't give any limit. Try a shorter one perhaps. Lastly, is there anything different in the structure of the reschedule message? Is it in a single part message with a mime type
"text/calendar; method=REQUEST"?

Comment: This is only a problem with an Exchange Server account. I checked around and other people have reported the same issue. The formatting is identical. Only DTSTART, DTEND, DTSTAMP, and SEQUENCE are different